# Is it okay to explore other grad school options while deferring admission due to COVID-19?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I’m from the West Coast, and I accepted my admissions offer into a master's program on the East Coast before COVID-19.

I would like to defer my admissions, but still apply to local universities just in case the current situation gets worse.

Note: I'm not getting scholarships. Also, I don't have family or friends living in the East Coast, so moving there right now sounds crazy to me.

Comment: If the program will be online, why do you have to move?

Comment: The answer depends on what agreements you have made with the university.  You should not trust an answer from someone who has not read those agreements.

Comment: So I assume that you are from Mauritania (West Coast of Africa) and want to move to Mozambique (East Coast of Africa). Bottom line, this is an international forum: don't assume that everybody knows you are from Africa (or the USA).

Comment: @MaartenBuis: When I first read your comment, I was happy for a quick moment that there is some user who does believe everybody knows their country and is not from the US (but from Africa). Then I read it again and understood it and got sad again.